# Who assigns subnet masks?

Tags: routes, network-protocols, subnet

When I type `ipconfig` I get a list of data points as expected, one of them being,

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.106(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
```

My laptop is currently connected to WiFi via my cellphone.

What I don't understand is where does the subnet mask come from? Does my phone give it to my laptop? And if so, why does it need to allow so many devices? Shouldn't it be more like `255.255.255.250`? Only 3 or 4 devices can use my phone as a hotspot at the same time anyway.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me clear up this confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subnet masks are determined by administrators. A device will either receive them through DHCP or it will be configured manually.

I'm not sure what the DHCP settings are on your phone, but in private networks it doesn't really matter if you waste address space. It's always best practice to use a subnet mask that fits your needs best.

I also think you meant 255.255.255.248 would be a better subnet mask for the DHCP on your phone. This subnet mask will provide 6 usable IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Subnet size is set by the device providing the IP addressing.   I'm sure that your phone by default is large is because that works for the majority of cases.

Also 255.255.255.250 is not a valid subnet mask.  [Here's a handy link.](http://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html)

Comment: Why don't the manufacturers of the phone set a smaller subnet mask?